# Python a word letter by letter backwards

Tags: python

I need to write word by letter in line. So if i write for example PYTHON the output should be

```
N
ON
HON
THON
YTHON
PYTHON
```

But with this code it goes:

```
P
PY
PYT
PYTH
PYTHO
PYTHON
```

here is my code:

```
word = input("input word: ")
r = " "
for sign in word:
   r = sign + r
   print(r)
```

Comment: Please don't tag your questions with the editor or IDE you use unless you are specifically asking a question about that editor or IDE.  The language tag is a different matter as it is completely relevant to code written in a particular language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were very close, but needed to use the `reversed` keyword on `word`:

```py
word = input("input word: ")
r = " "
for sign in reversed(word):
   r = sign + r
   print(r)
```

Output:

```
input word: house
e 
se 
use 
ouse 
house
```

Comment: Why did you start with `r = " "` ? There is an extra space at the end of the strings. btw I was upvoter.

Comment: I left as much as possible the same as the original author. If I were to re-write the code I don't think there would even be an `r` variable involved, much like the other answers. It's important that we keep answers as simple as possible though, in my opinion. For this question's context, it looks like `r` would be fine as an empty string, `r = ""`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution in case you don't want to concatenate strings multiple times...

```
inp = 'PYTHON'
print('\n'.join(inp[i:] for i in range(len(inp) - 1, -1, -1)))
```

Output :

```
N
ON
HON
THON
YTHON
PYTHON
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't need the variable `r`, this code might be more efficient for your purpose.

```
word = input("input word: ")
for i in range(1, len(word) + 1):
    print(word[-i:].upper())
```